# Using Android DatePickerFragment with two different buttons

Tags: android, android-fragments, datepicker

I am trying to make two different buttons open date-picking dialog and set the selected dates as text to the textView's next to each buttons.
I'm not sure how can i differentiate these to calls, i tried by Tag, but while debugging i saw the Views tag is null.
this is what i did so far:

DatePickerFragment.java:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
     if(view.getTag() == "datePicker1")
     {
        ((TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1)).
        setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
    }
    else
    { 
        if(view.getTag() == "datePicker2")
        {
            ((TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText2)).
            setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker1");
        }

    });



    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker2");
        }
    });
```

Please Help!

Comment: In `MainActivity` put `public static String TAG;` when button one click `TAG = "datePicker1"` for another button `TAG = "datePicker2"`. In `DatePickerFragment` use `MainActivity.TAG` now compare the string.

Answer (score 1):

It should not have happened. I guess you have a typo in your code. Post your whole code and we can find the typo.

Plus you don't need this:

`if(DatePickerFragment.this.getTag() == "datePicker1");`

Replace it with just :

`if (getTag()=="datePicker1")`

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution.
Apparently the Tag in the show() is for the fragment and not for the view so this is what i did:

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
     if(DatePickerFragment.this.getTag() == "datePicker1");
     {
        ((TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText1)).
        setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
    }

    if(DatePickerFragment.this.getTag() == "datePicker2")
    {
        ((TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editText2)).
        setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
    }


}
```

Now the first time i set the date it appears on the TextView, but for the second time i set the date (with the other button) i get the same date on the TextView2 as on the first TextView.

anyone knows why? How to fix this?